# RadGridView List Column Filtering

Tags: wpf, filter, radgridview

I am using RadGridView control on my WPF application. I have added a column filter for one of the columns (Category column) of my Grid.

The "Category" column is a List/Collection column. That can show multiple items for one row. And we need a filter for this "Category" column. So that filter should show the distinct categories only in filter popup.

Please check the screen shot below-

[image]

I am using the below code for getting the distinct values in filter dropdown-

```
    private void MyGrid_OnDistinctValuesLoading(object sender, GridViewDistinctValuesLoadingEventArgs e)
    {            
        e.ItemsSource = ((RadGridView)sender).GetDistinctValues(e.Column, false);
    }
```

Below XAML code for "Category column-

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="Category"                                                                                                   DataMemberBinding="{Binding CategoryList, Mode=OneWay}"                 
              FilterMemberPath="CategoryText"
              IsFilterable="True"                                                                                                                       
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"                                       
                                       ToolTip="Category"
                                       Text= "Category" />
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>

                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                                                                                                  
                                <ItemsControl x:Name="CategoryItemsControl"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Top"                                                                                                             
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border MinHeight="105"
                                                MaxHeight="105"                                                                                                      
                                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource IsabellineBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                           ToolTip="{Binding CategoryText}"
                                                           Text="{Binding CategoryText}"                                                               
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"                                                               
                                                           FontSize="12" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

But I am not getting the distinct values (as per the column "Category") in filter dropdown.

I want to show distinct values in filter dropdown as per the blue box in above image.

So can anyone let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Hi, can you share something more? Ie. how do you bind the data to the gridView? Do you have a class tha is rapresenting the items?

Comment: @GianlucaConte, I have updated the question.